# Symfony 2.8 Forms/Twig: Twig is rendering my input (type=date) incorrectly

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I am expecting that when the page is rendered, it would be input (type=date). But I am getting type=text.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <input id="test_form_studentdob" class="normal" type="text" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" name="test_form[studentdob]">
    </body>
</html>
```

I already tried this :

1. multiple browsers (both desktop and mobile)
2. removed all CSS/JS I was loading inside . This includes loading jQuery/jQuery/bootstrap UI libraries

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong? thanks

**snippet of Symfony controller:**

```
/**
 * @Route("/test")
 */
public function testAction(Request $request) {
    $form = $this->createForm(new TestFormType());
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    return $this->render(
        "AppBundle:SelfService:TestForm.html.twig"
        , array("form" => $form->createView())
    );
}
```

**Symfony Form type class:**

```
<?php
// src/appBundle/Form/TestFormType.php
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType
    , Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface
    , Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class TestFormType extends AbstractType {
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
                "attr" => array(
                        "id" => "testform"
                )
            )
        );
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
            ->setMethod("GET")
            ->add(
                "studentdob"
                , "date"
                , array(
                    "attr" => array(
                        "class" => "normal"
                        , "placeholder" => "DD-MM-YYYY"
                    )
                    , "format" => "dd-MM-yyyy"
                    , "required" => false
                    , "widget" => "single_text"
                )
            );
    }
}
```

This is my Twig template:

```
{% block body %}
    {{ form_widget(form.studentdob) }}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What is the field type in your Entity.

Comment: Also try removing this    , "widget" => "single_text"

Comment: @Filchev I edited my original post. But I'm not attaching my form to any entity since it's not related to one.

Comment: @Filchev from what I read on the Symfony site (http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/reference/forms/types/date.html#widget), widget = single_text is what renders the input to type=date

Comment: Sadly the thing that breaks your field type is the date format you require -> dd-MM-yyyy. I believe that the browsers do not support it. To achieve this functionality use some datetimepicker widget from jquery UI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [HTML date input](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.date.html) has an unique format : **yyyy-mm-dd**

> A valid full-date as defined in [RFC 3339](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/common-microsyntaxes.html#valid-date-string), with the additional
>   qualification that the year component is four or more digits
>   representing a number greater than 0.

If you want to use another format you MUST use a text input.

So Symfony use a text input coupled with a **pattern** attribute when you are specifying another format.